# "Drupal" in question titles?

Tags: support, faq, questions

Sometimes I see questions containing *Drupal* and the Drupal version in the title. Should I edit it out?

Answer (score 11):

It is useless to include *Drupal* in the question title. *Drupal Answers* is about Drupal, and it's implicit that every question is about Drupal; if it was not, the question would be off-topic. Edit the title and rephrase it in a way that it doesn't need *Drupal* in the title.

The Drupal version should be reported in the question text, not in the questions title. It could be the question is still relevant for other Drupal versions, and having the version up-front in the question title could confuse future users who could think the question is irrelevant for them.
If the question is really specific for a Drupal version, or for higher Drupal versions, then it should be put also in a tag, so that users can find the questions relevant for them.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the Drupal version and the site name ("Drupal Answers") is already part of the page title, so it is shown in Google search results.

Comment: The version tag appears in the title just in the case there aren't other more used tags; otherwise, it's them to appear in the title.

Comment: thanks, good to know!

Comment: Wouldn't it be good to re-look at this from the perspective of getting the content to be usable for a larger number of new developers out there who do not already know about drupal.stackexchange.com. Woudn't google rank the specific page higher in google results if it had Drupal as well in the title. The h1 tag for the page does not include the Drupal Keyword from the name "Drupal Answers". The title tag does have Drupal in it but the h1 tag does not. I suspect this would have a direct impact in the search results ranking.

Comment: @anoopjohn Adding _Drupal_ in the question titles doesn't increase the chance of finding the questions on Google. Infact, they appear already on Google without _Drupal_ in their title.

Comment: Yes, they are, but there is a missing keyword in the h1 tag. I am thinking that would have an impact on questions that don't otherwise have a drupal specific keyword as well in the rest of the title. Google likes to see h1 having relevant keywords.

Comment: @anoopjohn That doesn't make any difference.